# How to get element after current selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My question is maybe a bit unclear so i will give an example

```
    <table id="products">
        <tr id="P1" class="A1"><td>1x</td><td>Product 1</td><td>&euro; 9,50</td><td><a href="#">(x)</a></td></tr>
        <tr id="P2" class="A1"><td>1x</td><td>Product 2</td><td>&euro; 10,50</td><td><a href="#">(x)</a></td></tr>
    </table>
```

What i want to accomplish is the following function to work

```
    $('#bestelling tr').each(function(index) {
        var naam = $(this + " td + td").text();
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
        alert(id + " " + naam);
    });
```

Does anyone knows how i can accomplish this? Sorry for my brief explanation of the problem my english isn't that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#bestelling tr td:eq(1)').each(function(index) {
    var naam = $(this).text();
    var id = this.id; 
    alert(id + " " + naam);

    // The tr is:
    $(this).parent()
    // Or the DOM element:
    this.parentNode 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction, is there a way to accomplish this with the "this" keyword later on i won't use the each but will process the clicked tr

Comment: <Boooom> again! `:eq(1)` ++1.

Comment: @user1169526. The tr is simply: `$(this).parent()`

Comment: @user1169526. No problem, don't forget to accept an answer. Click on the check sign on the left of the answer that helped you. this helps others visitors in the future.

Comment: @user1169526 just posted the full solution for you below.

Comment: @haroonxml. But you select all the cells, not just the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
here you go mate. Run the code below: 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to get element after current selector</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table tr').click(function (e) {
                var naam = "";
                $(this).children().each(function () {
                    naam += $(this).html() + ' ';
                });

                alert(naam);
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="products">
    <tr id="P1" class="A1">
        <td>1x</td>
        <td>Product 1</td>
        <td>&euro; 9,50</td>
        <td><a href="#">(x)</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="P2" class="A1">
        <td>1x</td>
        <td>Product 2</td>
        <td>&euro; 10,50</td>
        <td><a href="#">(x)</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see how does this answer the question. At all!

Comment: @gdoron if you can read and understand the code you know the answer, its simnple.

Comment: OK I won't argue, if you think it does answer the question so be it.

Comment: @gdoron or may be I miss understood the question :)

Comment: @gdoron i see that thats why i said may be I miss understood the question :)